# C# ASP.net, storing and writing HTML with string variables

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, string

I have a form where users can enter a url to a YouTube video.  My code parses the url and creates an embed string that is stored in my database.  This looks something like:

```
string rawQuery = uri.Query;
int index = rawQuery.IndexOf("?");
if (index > 0)
                rawQuery = rawQuery.Substring(index).Remove(0, 1);
id = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(rawQuery).Get("v");

string embedURL = "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

This string gets stored in the database and retrieved later and printed to an HTML page.  However, the output ends up looking like this when I view the page source:

```
&lt;iframe width=&quot;640&quot; height=&quot;360&quot; src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com/embed/AXaoi6dz59A&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

How can I print this string so that it doesn't escape my quotes and less/greater than symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `@Html.Raw(string)`

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/

Answer (score 1):

If you use, for example, ViewBag to output the string in the view use

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.EmbedURL)
```

This tell the framework to not encode the string

Answer (score 0):

It's when you write the string in the page that it gets encoded. Use the `<%= %>` server tag to output the string without encoding it:

```
<%= embedURL %>
```

You can also wrap it in an `HtmlString` object to avoid the automatic encoding:

```
HtmlString html = new HtmlString(embedURL)
```

Then you can just output it as normal:

```
<%: html %>
```

or using razor:

```
@html
```

You can also use the `Html.Raw` method to wrap it in an `HtmlString` object:

```
@Html.Raw(embedURL)
```