# How can I convert angle-brackets to custom HTML in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, razor

I am using the EF to scaffold the MVC to retrieve the data from a SQL Server database. I have a column in the table that has `<tag>` for hyperscript/subscript; how can I handle those?

The column value in the database is like

```
Hc<1> H2<d> T18<c>
```

but in the web application, I need to display like this:

[image]

So I need to replace < with `<sup>` and > with `</sup>`

```
<td >
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainName)
</td>
```

Before the field is shown in the index page how can I escape the `<tags>` and show hyperscript/subscript instead

I tried like

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainName.Replace("<i>", "").Replace("</i>", "").Replace("<sup>", "<").Replace("</sup>", ">"))
```

But it throws error like
`nvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TResult>(Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression, ViewDataDictionary<TModel> viewData, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)`

*** EDIT ***

[image]

Table is not using any styling though

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table" >
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th width="10%">
         .......
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         @foreach (var item in Model.Inventorys)
          {
            <tr style="padding-left:2em">
              <td>
               @Html.Raw(item.StrainName.Replace("<", "<sup>").Replace(">", "</sup>")) 
               </td>
               .............
              </tr>
            }
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# ASP.net, storing and writing HTML with string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137206/c-sharp-asp-net-storing-and-writing-html-with-string-variables)

Comment: @Jazb I updated the question with what I tried

Comment: "I am using the EF to scaffold the MVC" - what does it mean?! What does your question have to do with Entity Framework?

Comment: I wanted to share that I didnot build the View from scratch instead EF did that

Comment: `<1>` and `<d>` are not HTML tags, that looks like some custom notation I'm unfamiliar with, but it looks like _everything_ in angle-brackets is meant to be superscript?

Comment: @Dai yes so I need to replace < with `<sup>` and > with `</sup>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your database contains text like this:

```
Hc<1> H2<d> T18<c>
```

And you want it rendered as HTML like this:

```
Hc<sup>1</sup> H2<sup>d</sup> T18<sup>c</sup>
```

which appears like this:

> Hc<sup>1</sup> H2<sup>d</sup> T18<sup>c</sup>

---

Then for a quick-and-dirty solution do this in your Razor (`.cshtml`) files:

```
@Html.Raw( item.StrainName.Replace( "<", "[sup]" ).Replace( ">", "</sup>" ).Replace( "[sup]", "<sup>" ) ) )
```

- The `.Replace` method only replaces a single substring at a time, so to replace `<` with `"<sup>"` and `>` with `"</sup>"` I initially thought that 2 calls to `.Replace` would be needed...

  - Like this:

    ```
    item.StrainName.Replace( "<", "<sup>" ).Replace( ">", "</sup>" )
    ```
- ...however that doesn't work because the second call to `.Replace` will match the `>` characters added by the first call to `.Replace` (from the the trailing `>` in `<sup>`)
- So 3 separate `.Replace` calls are needed:

  - The first call uses a different set of characters (`[` and `]`) to prevent adding new `>` characters that would be matched by the second call.
  - The second works as normal.
  - The third call then replaces the `[` and `]` with `<` and `>` from the first call.

---

You do not need to use `DisplayFor` or any other `___For` method. The `For` methods are for rendering HTML that (generally speaking) corresponds to "two-way" members of your form model (aka "data binding"). In this case this is just simple one-way rendering to static HTML.

A better approach would involve validating the text against a regular-expression to ensure the angle-brackets are balanced and so won't break your HTML with unbalanced `<sup>` tags (e.g., prevent invalid text from being rendered like `Hc>1>> H2d<` - which is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I tried doing `@Html.Raw( item.StrainName.Replace( "<", "<sup>" ).Replace( ">", "</sup>" ) )` It removed the < and > and now shows like `Hc1 H2d T18c`  instead of the superscripts

Comment: @trx What does the **rendered** HTML look like, exactly? The `@Html.Raw` should not be removing angle-brackets by itself - it's possible you have a CSS rule applied that removes `<sup>`'s superscript effect.

Comment: I have updated the question what I am seeing in the browser and what is in theere while debugging

Comment: @trx Thank you for the screenshot, but you still haven't posted the rendered HTML is (i.e. "View Source" of the web-page, not how it visually looks). I appreciate that I wasn't clear earlier on.

Comment: sorry I updated the question.. I see in the rendered HTML `<sup>` tags but not in the table..I have also added the table I am using, I am not doing any styling here any particular styling

Comment: Just seeing it is replacing like `Thy1<sup</sup>a</sup>`

Comment: @trx Ah, ugh - that's a silly embarrassing bug in  my code - hold on.

Comment: @trx I've updated my answer, see the new version with 3 calls to `.Replace`.